# MacBook Pro experiencing random restarts and buggy behavior while running programs

Tags: macbook-pro, security, malware, big-sur

My MacBook Pro (15inch Mid 2014) has been displaying odd behavior (slowdowns, problems running certain software packages including jGRASP, beach balls, delays in expected restarts, as well as unexpected restarts) for the last few weeks. The only thing that I can think of is I updated it to Big Sur. However, my issues started several days before I updated it. I reset the PRAM, SMC and ran Malwarebytes but the issues persist. Could someone please advise me on additional steps to take?

Comment: When you have issues, you don't want to compound them by upgrading to a brand new release of an OS.  Reinstalling is also the last thing you want to do. Start by booting into Safe Mode to see if it's a 3rd party app or kext causing the problem.

Comment: I was not able locate the issue in safe mode but I did not locate. However, an additional issue has started. If I restart my MacBook and attempt to login it will restart a second time.

Comment: Is this a new question or an answer to your original problem?

Comment: Use your mac as usual for sometime. When you encounter issues, open console and check for errors and faults in the log. Please post those errors here. See how to do this - [View log messages in Console on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/console/log-messages-cnsl1012/mac). (Note: click 'edit' below your answer to add more info).

Answer (score 3):

**"Could someone please advise me on additional steps to take?"**

1. Check Activity Monitor (in /Applications/Utilities) to see if any processes are using excessive CPU% or Memory.
2. Make sure that all the software you use is up-to-date, and compatible with Big Sur.  *(Very often, the cause of problems after upgrading the OS is because of old, incompatible software that is crashing or hanging -- particularly 'invisible' background processes.)*
3. Create a new user account and test the problem there. If the problem goes away, you know that something in your old user account was causing it. It might be a Login Item, Launch Agent or other process that's programmed to launch, or settings/preferences that are incorrect or corrupt. Go back to the old user account and investigate. If the problem continues, then you know it's a System-level issue, not a user-level one.
4. Check the logs for messages about crashes, unexpected restarts, and other errors. https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/console/cnsl1012/mac

It's also possible that problems like unexpected restarts are caused by hardware problems, such as battery, power supply or logic board issues.